# In django, why get_or_create doesn't work if the items contain ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

The models defines like the following, Cases has multi Keyword as ForeignKeyword,

```
from django.db import models

class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    keywords = models.ForeignKey(Keyword)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

If I want to use create get_or_create, it will show that I missed a Keyword_id, like this:

```
 case, flag = Case.objects.get_or_create(name = 'case_name', keywords__name = 'keyword_name')
```

got a message:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: dbtest_case.keywords_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate/get_or_create `Keyword` first:

```
keyword, _ = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(name='keyword_name')
case, flag = Case.objects.get_or_create(name='case_name', keywords=keyword)
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: OK, it seems what I thought is right, in this case, has to create the keyword first. Thanks very much.